# Cannot make an array of Nodes

Tags: java, generics, skip-lists

I get the following error when trying to create an array of Nodes:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LSkipList$Node;

This is my code:

```
    public class Node {
      Key key;
      Value val;
      Node[] next;

      //constructor
      public Node(Key k, Value v) {
        key = k;
        val = v;
        next = (Node[])new Object[MAX_LEVEL];

      }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you making a new array of objects and casting it to an array of nodes instead of just making an array of nodes?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
new Object[MAX_LEVEL]
```

means "a new array of type `Object[]` and size `MAX_LEVEL` where every element is `null`".

---

This:

```
(Node[])new Object[MAX_LEVEL]
```

means the same, plus "but check if it has type `Node[]`; if not, raise `ClassCastException`". But that's redundant, because you just created the array with type `Object[]`, so you *know* it doesn't have type `Node[]`. So it will *always* raise `ClassCastException`.

---

Instead, you need to write this:

```
new Node[MAX_LEVEL]
```

which means "a new array of type `Node[]` and size `MAX_LEVEL` where every element is `null`".